# how to open marker window from another event using Gmap4rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Hi i am showing list of trucks in the map and table view..once i click the truckno in the table view, i want to zoom the particular truck in the map and infowindow of the truck should be open automatically..

I am using https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

My map construction code

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>)
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
```

I can able to view the markers in the map . no issue here.

But markers[0].infowindow.open is not working while clicking the truck# from the table.
i found that markers[0].infowindow is null. [Assume that i am clicking the first truck]

Can someone please help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you have a look at the freshly created example page I've made: http://apneadiving.github.io/

Go to the sidebar section and look at the code, especially:

```
marker.panTo();
google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
```

Indeed, infowindow creation is made on click, not before, for perf concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.. I think this is what exactly i am looking for. Let me take look at the code and come back to you if i have any issue.

Comment: Found one more issue, Can you zoom out and make sure you are not seeing any marker and you can see the no of markers in the map.Now if you click the name in sidebar, the infowindow is not displaying.

Comment: yeah... its a drawback of the clusterer which set map to null in markers, I wonder whether or not I should pass the map object to markers...

Comment: I'd suggest to zoom on the marker first, let me edit my example page